# Selecting a Value for a DojoComboBox using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, dojo

I'm trying to build a data scraper with Selenium Python that searches a webpage. The search page contains a dojoComboBox that allows you to select a name from a dropdown list.

Here is the HTML for the dojoComboBox:

```
<span _="whitespace and CR's between tags adds &nbsp; in FF" class="dojoComboBoxOuter dj_khtml dj_safari dropSel" style="null">
    <input style="display:none" tabindex="-1" name="txtCaseName" value="" dojoattachpoint="comboBoxValue">
    <input style="display:none" tabindex="-1" name="txtCaseName_selected" value="" dojoattachpoint="comboBoxSelectionValue">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="dojoComboBox dropSel" dojoattachevent="key:_handleKeyEvents; keyUp: onKeyUp; compositionEnd; onResize;" dojoattachpoint="textInputNode" style="null">
    <img hspace="0" vspace="0" class="dojoComboBox dropSel" dojoattachpoint="downArrowNode" dojoattachevent="onMouseUp: handleArrowClick; onResize;" src="dojo/src/widget/templates/images/combo_box_arrow.png" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;">
</span>
```

I can get the DojoComboBox scroll menu to open with the following code:

```
dropdown = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("img.dojoComboBox")
dropdown.click()
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to actually select one of the values.

Update:
The HTML I posted above is from the page I pull up when I inspect elements (the HTML under the 'Elements' tab of Chrome DevTools). I've been looking at some other files that I found in the 'Source' tab, and I found some code in a page called main.aspx?e=nauqov2blnhlnh45eseztnao that looks also related to the DojoComboBox:

```
<select name="txtCaseName" id="txtCaseName" class="dropSel"dojotype="ComboBox" 
setSelectedValue="dojo.byId('txtCaseName1').value=arguments[0]" 
autocomplete="true" dataurl="CaseCode.aspx?match=%{searchString}&amp;lang=e" 
mode="remote" maxlistlength="7">
</select>
```

However, neither of these seem to encode options that I can select. I thought that perhaps the options would be stored in the url labeled 'dataurl' in the piece of HTML above, but when I copy that link into my address bar, it doesn't take me to a valid webpage. From what I've found in the Dojo documentation, it seems like the options should be stored in a separate file/database, but I can't find any suggestions about how to access that file.

Any suggestions? (Thanks!)

Comment: Do you mind posting the rest of your code along with any attempt made to solve the problem? Personally, I usually use Selenium to load the webpage and BeautifulSoup to actually scrape the data. Maybe that might work?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to store every options in a list. Then based on some conditions such as name of option, you can choose it and click on it.

```
all_options = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("your locator for every options")
for options in all_options:  
  if "option_name" in options.text.strip():  
     options.click()
```

Comment: Where can I find the values for 'your locator for every options', and for 'option_name'? Those values don't seem to be in the HTML. I used the following code: options = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.dojoComboBox>input[name^='txtCaseName']"), based on a suggestion on another thread, but that didn't actually get any options. Any suggestions for revisions so that I can actually access the options? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the HTML code for at least 2 options. and in place option_name , you can write your desire element (which you want to select from drop down).

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any encoded options - see edits to post above